# Using a var from a text file

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

My problem is that I would like to use the function launched by the keyword received in carac from a text file, and use the string right after carac in this function that is in an other file included but I have no idea how to do it.

```c++
for(std::string carac; fichier>>carac;)
{
    auto found = _map.find(carac);
    if(found != _map.end()
    {
        found->second();
        pile_double.afficher(); // Pile is the french word for a LIFO Queue, afficher is the one for display
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly all you need to do is extract again:

```
if (found != _map.end())
{
    std::string name;
    fichier >> name; // this is the second word

    found->second();
    pile_double.afficher();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure it's going to work. I want to extract that second word and use it in my function, launched with the keyword from the map, and use it in an other file (named function.cpp)

Comment: @ALEX- Yes, you're telling me what you want to do but I don't see how this code won't work in that scenario. Could you please be more elaborate on how my answer doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what your code was doing. I tried it and it worked !

Comment: Little update : I tried your code, and it (almost?) worked. In name I received the second word, but in my function this second word wasn't used

Comment: @ALEX- How are you accessing the second word from the function?

Comment: This is the purpose is my post ^^. I have no idea how to do it

Comment: @ALEX- Okay then, your function should take a parameter of type `std::string const&`. And then pass `name` with `found->second(name)`. Then your function will have access.

Comment: Maybe I did it wrong, but I have an error : no match for call to '(std::function<void()>) (std::string&)'
found ->second(name);

Comment: no match for call to '(std::function<void()>) (std::string&)' found ->second(name);

Comment: @ALEX- You need to update the type of your map too: `map<string, function<void (string const&)>>`

Comment: I tried it, but it's a little bit complicated, because there are like 10-15 functions in my map, so updating the type of the map is not that easy ^^

Comment: @ALEX- Well then there's no other way that I know of. That's the way it should be done, because how else is the function going to be able to know what `name` is?

Comment: I'm creating an other map which will contain only the functions that need map<string, function<void (string const&)>>. What do you think about it ?

Comment: @ALEX- If that will make things easier I say go for it. :)

Comment: @ALEX- No problem. Glad I could help! Could you also accept my answer (click the checkmark)?